# Publishing multiple web services to the same Azure VM

Tags: c#, azure, web-services, wcf

**Short story:** 
Can I publish more than one WCF web service to a single Azure VM? When I publish one, it appears to "overwrite" the other (I can use the new one but old one stops working).

**Longer Story:** 
I have a web service which I published to an Azure VM and it's been working well. I recently started building another web service as another project in the same solution as the original web service. However, it doesn't seem that I can host more than one web service on the same Azure VM.

Let's say I publish service A and test it to make sure it works. Then I publish service B, and that works too. However, that causes service A to stop working. If I republish service A then that causes service B to stop working.

This leads me to believe that you can only publish one WCF service to an Azure VM at a time, unless I'm doing something wrong?

I could combine them both into one service, but I really don't want to do that as the business logic and purpose is different for each one. Is my solution to have a second VM?

Comment: You can do almost anything you could on a local/owned PC on an Azure VM, including hosting 100s of WCF services if you so choose. There must be something fundamental about your deployment that needs changing.

Comment: @sellotape It's weird, because I'm able to access the folder listing, where it shows the web services (https://i.imgur.com/R1hnEW2.png), and am able to click each one and view the main page. However, when I try to query an endpoint I get a 400 error. Any ideas on what could be causing this? Possibly something in the Web.config files?

Comment: First, you should create a new web site application which could be the optional publishing choice when we publish the web service in the IIS. Then we are supposed to enable the inbound rules in the VM network, which could open an additional port on the internet.